# Tilt levels of factors at plot.design comand (tilt

Tags: r, plot

I`d like to tilt the level of factor at plot.design command in r

```
require(stats)
plot.design(warpbreaks)
```

If I execute the code above the the figure will show the levels at horizontal direction, but I`d like to tilt the levels 45 degrees. This will help me a lot to better show the levels of my aplication 
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat cumbersome to do outside of ggplot2, but doable.

```
plot.design(warpbreaks, axes = FALSE) # plot with no axes
axis(2) # add y as predefined by default
# manually add text in place of the label
text(1:2, par("usr")[3], labels = c("wool", "tension"), srt = 45, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE)
box() # you need this to have the square around your image
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, actually I`m trying to tilt the levels ("A","B" and "L","M","H") and not the factors (wool, tension). Any idea how to do that?